# regular expression - to find first value not matching a constant string in comma-separated list

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sh

Title says it all. I am trying to build a regular expression but failing miserably. The task is to return the first string in a comma-separated list that is NOT matching a 'forbidden' constant string. The 'forbidden' string can occur anywhere in the list and (in theory) could occur multiple times in the list.

For example (When the 'forbidden' string = "TBD"):

```
"TBD,Smith" --> need to return Smith
"TBD,TBD,TBD,Jones,Edwards" --> need to return Jones
"ABC,TBD,Smith" --> need to return ABC
"TBD,DEF-9gh,GHI,JKLMNOpqrst,Any old string" --> need to return DEF-9gh
```

Any regex ninjas out there who know how to do this?

Comment: _Failing miserably ..._ -- could you post examples?

Comment: What defines "forbidden"? 3 capital letters?

Comment: No, the string TBD. It could also be that the forbidden string does not occur at all... eg1: ABC -> return ABC .... eg2: ABC,DEF --> return ABC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -P`:

```
s="ABC,TBD,Smith"
echo "$s"|grep -oP '(^|,)\K(?!TBD)[^,]+'|head -1
ABC

s="TBD,TBD,TBD,Jones,Edwards"
echo "$s"|grep -oP '(^|,)\K(?!TBD)[^,]+'|head -1
Jones

s="TBD,DEF-9gh,GHI,JKLMNOpqrst,Any old string"
echo "$s"|ggrep -oP '(^|,)\K(?!TBD)[^,]+'|head -1
DEF-9gh
```

And if your grep doesn't support `-P` then here is an **awk solution**:

```
echo "$s" | awk -F '(TBD,)*|,' '{print $1$2; exit}'
DEF-9gh
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand your question correctly?

`awk`:

```
$ awk -F',' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!="TBD"){print $i;next}}}' input.txt
Smith
Jones
ABC
DEF-9gh
```

A POSIX-compliant shell solution:

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/sh

while read -r line; do
        IFS=,
        for token in ${line}; do
                if [ "${token}" != TBD ]; then
                        echo "${token}"
                        continue 2
                fi
        done
done <<EOT
TBD,Smith
TBD,TBD,TBD,Jones,Edwards
ABC,TBD,Smith
TBD,DEF-9gh,GHI,JKLMNOpqrst,Any old string
EOT
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
Smith
Jones
ABC
DEF-9gh
```

or just

```
get_token()
(
    IFS=,
    for t in $@; do
        [ "$t" != TBD ] && echo "$t" && break
    done
)

get_token "TBD,TBD,TBD,Jones,Edwards" # => "Jones"
```